# What does an optimizer optimize c++ or assembly

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Do optimizers (generally speaking here) take my c/c++ code and write better c/c++ code or do they translate it straight into assembly and then optimize that.  Or is it a combo?

**EDIT:**
I am using gcc (but I would like to know what others do also)

Comment: Which particular optimizer do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizers can be at different levels, but usually they won't generate new readable code (although sometimes this happens with other languages, like JavaScript for example.)

GCC generates an intermediate representation:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/GCC-Frontend-HOWTO-4.html

Optimizations are then applied to this structure.  See more here, for example:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Tree-SSA.html

From there, the backend translates it to final machine code (although I believe this part also involves optimizations, as well.)

Comment: Other compilers, e.g. clang, also use intermediate representations of what the code *does*.  In clang's case, that's what LLVM optimizes before emitting asm or machine code for the target machine.  BTW, the "target specific" optimizations like replacing `mov reg, 0` with `xor reg,reg` on x86, or taking advantage of `lea` for various things, are called "peephole" optimizations

Answer (score 2):

> Do optimizers ...

Well, *optimizers* (or better optimization strategies) come with particular compiler implementations.

There's no general answer for your question

---

> and write better c/c++ code or do they translate it straight into assembly

No, their job is to optimize the backend code, which might be target assembly or whatever intermediate machine code. Thus there's no intermediate optimized c++ code to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Optimizer don't rewrite c/c++ code.

The compiler does a lexical analysis, and then makes a semantic analysis using some kind of internal graph representation of your code. The optimizer first works on this internal representation to identify and [optimize the flow of execution](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_code_optimization.htm) (for example constant propagation).

Once the code generation can start, the optimizer intervenes again, to make macine dependent optimization (register allocation, special instruction sets such as intel's [MMX](http://www.drdobbs.com/mmx-technology-code-optimization/184411044), etc...)

Only at the end does it generate assembler code.